# SolrCloud Zookeeper bootstrap option | Solr 7

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I am managing a solrcloud running with 4 solr nodes and 5 zookeeper instances. Solr version is 4.4.

We are planning for an upgrade to the latest version of 7.

Solr node1 is started with bootsrap_conf=true. For any update to schema or configset, we update configset in node1 and do a restart.

My issue is that I dont see that option in solr 7. We have around 200 cores with individual configset for most of them. I read that, with solr7, zookeeper stores the configset. But I dont see from where zookeeper will load this.

If I shut down my entire solr cloud (including zookeeper), how do I reload the configsets to zookeeper ? Do I need to track which configset is used for each core ? Or is there an option like bootstrap_conf in Solr 7 which will load the respective conf to zookeeper.

Comment: Updating a config would then be `bin/solr zk upconfig -n <name for configset> -d <path to directory with configset>` instead of restarting, wouldn't it? See [Using Zookeeper to manage configuration files](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/using-zookeeper-to-manage-configuration-files.html) - if I understood your current use of `bootstrap_conf`. If you're using config sets, updating a config set should update it for all collections using that config set.

Comment: This may help you http://vinodtechstuff.blogspot.com/2017/08/solr-in-production.html

Comment: I agree we can upload the config using cli. My question is, let us say I have 10 collectoins and I am using 10 different configsets for each. I am shutting down all of my solr and zookeeper instances. During the next start, I bring up zookeeper first, then solr. How does solr loads the collection ? How does it know which configset to use for each collection.
With bootstrap_conf, I can specify to load the collection using the configset from the conf directory and I just need to start this server and it will be uploaded to zookeeper. Is there a similar way to do it in Solr7

Comment: Maybe I am understanding Solr 7 methods differently, In 4.4 version, I keep the configset inside core/conf directory of node1 and with bootstrap_conf=true set in node1, I just need to restart node1 to update the changes. Yes restarting is a bad idea, but I have around 300-400 cores with individual configset. This way I dont have to keep track of which configset to used for which core, but update the conf directory and restart node1. Or during a maintenance, just shut down entire solrcloud and while restarting, bring zookeeper ensemble up and start with node1.